# Отправка писем шаблоном

Tags: php, email

Здравствуйте. Нужно отправлять пользователям письма с информацией, для этого я хочу использовать шаблоны .tpl. Сайт использует smarty, пробовал через него - никакой реакции. Писал свою функцию, шаблон цеплялся, но передавался только один параметр.
Короче, нужна функция, которая принимает на вход n-кол-во переменных со значениями, подключает указанный .tpl шаблон и отправляет на нужную почту.

Comment: пишете на чистом php или какую cms используйте? каким образом tpl подключаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень даже советую не изобретать велосипедов, а использовать то, что уже дано :)

http://webi.ru/webi_files/php_libmail.html

Comment: @kohana вы не поняли, мне нужно именно цеплять .tpl и запихивать данные :)